# Alfresco Javascript Action to remove all cm:contains but primary parent

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a workflow that will place files into different folders for linking purposes using cm:contains to the other folders. Sometimes we need to remove these links. I am working on an alfresco script that will remove all associations of cm:contains to all other folders but from the parent association. If there are no associations of cm:contains but the parent, then I wont do anything. I was trying to do something like this

```
var parentAssociations = document.parentAssocs["cm:contains"];

for(var i =0; i < parentAssociations.length; i++){      
 if(document.primaryParentAssociation !== parentAssociations[i]){ 
     parentAssociations[i].removeAssociation(document, "cm:contains");
   }        
 }
```

However I keep getting errors when trying to do this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by using the parent methods instead

```
var primaryParent = document.parent;
    var parents = document.parents;
    for(var parent in parents){
         if(parents[parent].nodeRef + "" !== primaryParent.nodeRef + ""){
                  parents[parent].removeAssociation(document, "cm:contains");
                  parents[parent].removeNode(document);
         }
    }
```